# parsing json result with generics

Tags: android, json, generics, gson

I have an app which sends a REST request to a server and receives a JSON response back. However, my REST client service on the app may send out several different types of REST request which will result in different responses causing different types of objects being created on the client android app. Each response will always be an array of some type of object.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Override
    protected List<?> doInBackground(String... urls) {    
        requestType = urls[0];
        InputStream source = retrieveStream(Constants.REST_SERVER_URL + requestType);    
        Gson gson = new Gson();         
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        List<?> result = gson.fromJson(reader, List.class);         
        return result;          
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<?> result) {
        if(requestType.equals(Constants.GET_OSM_POI_NODES)) {
            Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(result.size()));

            ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
            for(Object o : result) {
                // create a node object from the result
            }   
        }       
    }
```

In the onPostExecute method I want to create the correct object based on what REST url was used. So for example, if the url corresponding to GET_OSM_POI_NODES was used then it would construct an ArrayList of node objects which consists of a latitude and a longitude along with an id. Here is a sample JSON response for such an object:

```
[
    {
        "id": 353941,
        "lat": 754030751,
        "lon": -39701762
    }, 
     ...
```

The problem is that the result passed into onPostExecute is always a List of generic objects because I want it to be generic. I am not sure how to create Node objects from these generic types. Even if I don't use generics the objects passed into onPostExecute are list of StringMap and I don't know how to create different types of object from these.

Any ideas?

Anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use the JSON parser? http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html

Comment: I'm using GSon because it is possible for my returned Json to be very large and I read that GSon is suitable for processing very large results

Comment: Ahh, missed your parser. Sorry.